# PHP change language in site [Selector]

Tags: php, cookies

I want to build a function that can choose a lanugage (Default is english) and I want it to be saved for while.
I have files of translates in include like :

> $lang['send'] = 'Send';

source /langs/**en**/lang.php *(en/ru/ar)

Any ideas how to do it? 
Maybe with cookies? 
I want it secure

Comment: You can save preferred language to user's profile in database if it is a registered user, otherwise your best solution is cookies. you just need to save selected language in cookie, not all the translation. its not an important data to be secured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session for that

```
session_start();

// Set session lang
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';

// Load lang vars
require('/langs/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.php');
```

Comment: But I want the session will saved for 7 days for example

Comment: yes, you can save that for 7 days, to know more about session configuration see  http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php